# Comparing Text on PostgreSQL 8.4 and 9.1

Tags: postgresql, locale

I have two databases, one is running on postgresql 8.4 and the other on postgresql 9.1.
Both are on CentOS machines with the same locale (`en_US`).

Suppose i have a table with this data:

```
id | description
1    Morango
2    CAFÉ
3    pera
4    Uva
```

The odd thing is, when i run a query like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE description ~* 'café'
```

On the 8.4 machine i get no results, but on the 9.1 machine i got the row (`CAFÉ`).
Apparently they differ on how to compare the upcase unicode character.

1. Could someone give me some insight about this problem?
2. Is it the different version o postgresql that can cause this problem?
3. Are there any additional configuration i could make to equalize the behavior from the two machines?

UPDATE: Both databases are UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case-insensitive regex matching for non-US Unicode characters was basically not supported before 9.0.

See this snippet in the [9.0 release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/release-9-0.html):

> E.14.3.6. Functions
>   [...]
>   Support locale-specific regular expression processing with UTF-8
>   server encoding (Tom Lane)
>
> Locale-specific regular expression functionality includes
>   case-insensitive matching and locale-specific character classes.
>   Previously, these features worked correctly for non-ASCII characters
>   only if the database used a single-byte server encoding (such as
>   LATIN1). They will still misbehave in multi-byte encodings other than
>   UTF-8.